# Continuation in Scheme with lambda with no arguments

Tags: scheme, continuations

So I am dealing with continuations and have something like this:

```
(or
    (call/cc (lambda (cont)
           ...
          (if ( ... )
              (cons randomList (lambda() (cont #f)))
              #f)})}
     ( do something else)
```

I was wondering what the difference between (lambda() (cont #f)) and (cont #f) are. I get the answer I want with the lambda and something wrong without. Could someone explain the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nullary (zero arguments) lambda used in this way is called a *thunk*.

Thunks are used in Scheme to defer the execution of some piece of code. Suppose, for example, that we're talking about `(display #f)` instead of `(cont #f)`. If you wrote `(display #f)` directly, then when the code execution reached that point, it'd display `#f` straight away, whereas if you wrapped it in a thunk (`(lambda () (display #f))`), it wouldn't display the `#f` until you invoked the thunk.

Back to your code, a `(cont #f)` in the code would cause an immediate jump at the point where the continuation is invoked. Wrapping it in a thunk delays the invocation of the continuation until you invoke the thunk.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So this means that ( do something else) will be called when the thunk is invoked later. Is this correct?

Comment: Right, that appears to be the case based on my understanding of your code.